# How to start the main class in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am a newbie to WPF.I have a problem in developing the WPF application where I want to start a class as start up object,after I want to Show the welcome form. When I was trying to put the main method in that class set the project properties startup object as that class.
I am getting this error **"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."**.

How can we resolve this error by making the main method of that class as startup object?

Comment: It might be sufficient to write `[STAThread]` over your main method.

Answer (score 3):

in top App.xaml

```
Exit="App_Exit"
Startup="App_Startup"
```

in app.xaml.cs

```
void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
private void App_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
```

There other events you can subscribe to, if you are really needing to override App as startup you need define in your Program.cs like this:

```
public static class Program
    {

        [STAThread]
        [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
```

And somewhere in there

```
App app = new App();
app.InitializeComponent();
app.Run();
```

Answer (score -1):

When you say "welcome form" do you mean `Window`?

Have you tried setting the StartupUri of the App.xaml?

```
<Application x:Class="DemoApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="WelcomeWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that also ,But before that I want the main class to execute .

Comment: Have you tried overriding the OnStartup event of the App class?